# Return Powershell result in Excel via VBA

Tags: vba, powershell, excel

I created sample VBA function in .xlam module and I want to return simple Powershell Get-Date string:

```
Private Function test1() As String
    test1 = Shell("Powershell Get-Date")
End Function
```

In Excel's cells when I try to run that 
=test1()
there are 4 digits numbers:

```
1456
1296
4228
1232
4976
5328
4844
4560
2572
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

As [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278437.aspx), `Shell()` doesn't return the output of the external command, but its task ID. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2788365/1630171) to a similar question if you want to read the command output.

If you just want to get a string with the current timestamp: there's no need to shell out to PowerShell for that. Something like this should work just fine:

```
Private Function test1() As String
  test1 = CStr(Now)
End Function
```