# R Output Variable to Excel

Tags: r, vba, excel

I am working on a project using excel VBA as a user interface to R.  In the VBA code I call the R script using the shell.run method.  It opens the command prompt and runs r through that.  The r code performs functions and at the end writes data to an excel file and saves it in my documents.  If there are any errors, I want it to stop before the VBA code continues.  We have implemented error handling in the r script with booleans. Is there a way for R to return these variables to VBA?  Any other thoughts on how to get the error handling messages from R to VBA before the rest of the code continues would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: You could use one of the R packages that lets you create excel files, create one, and use your VBA to import it when it gets a signal from R that the file writing is done. Probably.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  We thought of that but were hoping to avoid creating another file as that seems a little bit clunky.  Was hoping for a more streamlined method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784367/capture-output-value-from-a-shell-command-in-vba