# VBA could find R library

Tags: r, vba, excel

I am trying to use `EXCEL` as the front end for a `R script`. So far, I tested my `R script` in `Windows CMD` but I could not make it work in `VBA`. The error message is `Error in library(readxl) : there is no package called 'readxl'`. So it looks like `VBA` environment is picky.

1. Any suggestions on fixing this error? (fixed now)
2. Is there a way to run `R script` and save the function returned value (now it is 5) into a variable in `VBA`? I can do this by saving a text file and load again, but not sure if there is a better way to handle this.

#### a simple example of R script, which defines a function and calls it later.

```
est_var_dw <- function(){
    library(readxl)
    library(minpack.lm)
    library(msm)
    return(2+3)
}
est_var_dw()
```

#### a simple example of VBA

```
Sub run_r()
    Dim shell As Object
    Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
    Dim style As Integer: style = 1
    Dim errorCode As Integer
    Dim path As String
    path = """" & Cells.Range("B1") & """ """ & Cells.Range("B2") & """ &  Pause"

    errorCode = shell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)
End Sub
```

### Update

I figured out the first issue was due locations of different R packages, which can be solved by using `.libpath`

```
.libPaths(c(R_library_pth1, R_library_pth2))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good function for the second part of your question here: [Capture output value from a shell command in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784367/capture-output-value-from-a-shell-command-in-vba)

> [bburns-km](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243392/bburns-km) defines a vba function ShellRun:
>
> ```
> Public Function ShellRun(sCmd As String) As String
>
>     'Run a shell command, returning the output as a string'
>
>     Dim oShell As Object
>     Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
>
>     'run command'
>     Dim oExec As Object
>     Dim oOutput As Object
>     Set oExec = oShell.Exec(sCmd)
>     Set oOutput = oExec.StdOut
>
>     'handle the results as they are written to and read from the StdOut object'
>     Dim s As String
>     Dim sLine As String
>     While Not oOutput.AtEndOfStream
>         sLine = oOutput.ReadLine
>         If sLine <> "" Then s = s & sLine & vbCrLf
>     Wend
>
>     ShellRun = s
>
> End Function
> ```

As long as RScript.exe is in your PATH, you can then call from VBA:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ScriptPath As String
Dim StringOut As String

ScriptPath = "C:\...\test.R" 'Your Path Here

'Assign
StringOut = ShellRun("RScript " & ScriptPath)

'Print
Debug.Print StringOut

End Sub
```

Anything that your R script prints to console during session will be returned to VBA as a string