# translate code from batch to vba

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, powerbi

I have this batch file that look for the process name `msmdsrv.exe`, get the `PID number` using `tasklist` then get the `port number` using `netstat` where the connection type is established.

At the end it will export the result into a file `PBD_Port.csv`

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%F in ('tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq msmdsrv.exe" /fo csv') do ( 
set var=%%F
)

for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%h in ('netstat -ano ^| findstr ESTABLISHED ^|   findstr %var%') do ( 
set var1=%%h
)

echo %var1% > PBD_Port.csv
```

I use this code to get the port number of the *PowerBi Desktop*, as it do change every time when we launch *Power Bi Desktop*.

Is it possible to have a macro in Excel that do the same thing ?
so instead of using a batch file where the user has to click on it, i want a macro to give the same result and write the result not in a CSV but in a worksheet.

edit : i built the code for the batch, I wanted a general advice how to translate this to VBA, thanks for your comment

edit : actually, i was over complicating things, the port number is already stored in a temporary text file generated by the new SSAS instance, see different solution here

http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/connect-to-powerbi-desktop/td-p/87310

Comment: Your question is far too broad here; narrow it by showing your attempts! Note that CSV files do not have multiple worksheets, it is a simple text file only, hence there is no "active worksheet"!

Comment: This site is about helping people who try, not to spoon feed everyone. Show us some attempts and we will give in. Good luck :)

Comment: if you know what the batch script is doing, in VBA you can get the output of a shell command in a string variable with something like `stringResult = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("tasklist /nh /fi ""imagename eq msmdsrv.exe"" /fo csv").StdOut.ReadAll` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784367/capture-output-value-from-a-shell-command-in-vba

Comment: thanks for that, i will try that