# How to retrieve data from a SQLite Database in VBA in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am connecting to the .db file from VBA with ADO following the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509154/accessing-a-sqlite-database-in-vba-in-excel). My code connects correctly but it does not retrieve correct data from the table. In my table i have several columns, the first is INT the second is TEXT and the rest are all INT.

```
Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
Dim strSQL As String
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")


conn.Open "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC  Driver;Database=C:\Path\To\SQLite\Database.db;"

strSQL = "SELECT * from paston"


rst.Open strSQL, conn


Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst
rst.Close


Set rst = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing
```

The problem is when i select all on the sheet i only the get the first column `idx`, and if i select only the TEXT column it will not output anything, if i select any other column it will retrieve the numbers as integers but they are longs,

Comment: Does it help to actually name the columns in the SQL statement or just use the table name?

Comment: @MP24 no it does not help if i select a single column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After giving up, and coming back i watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VS_H2_vCgk8) and i spotted a difference:
    `rst.Open strSQL, conn, 1, 1`

and this allowed me to copy the entire table and paste it onto the sheet