# Connect to Sqlite Database using VBA

Tags: excel, database, vba, sqlite

My VBA code to connect to the Sqlite Database

```vb
Sub LoadValues()

   Dim conn As Object, rst As Object

   Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

  ' OPEN CONNECTION
  'Am getting Error at this line
   conn.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 (*.db,   *.accdb)};DBQ=E:\VBA_Project_Demo\Demo\demo.db;"


  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM test "

  ' OPEN RECORDSET
   rst.Open strSQL, conn

   ' OUTPUT TO WORKSHEET
   Worksheets("results").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst
   rst.Close

  ' FREE RESOURCES
 Set rst = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

The error message while executing
[image]

Control Panel ODBC Link
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't that be `"DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC  Driver;Database=E:\VBA_Project_Demo\Demo\demo.db;"` ?

Comment: For `SQLite` use something like `conn.Open "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=E:\VBA_Project_Demo\Demo\demo.db;"` and for Access use something lile `conn.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=E:\VBA_Project_Demo\Demo\demo.accdb;"`

Comment: @Jeeped actually i tried that syntax also as you mentioned, but again am getting the same error

Comment: @SiddharthRout as per your syntax, it for MS Access, which takes *.mbd file, but am trying to connect with SQLite, please suggest some other solutions or syntax

Comment: I have used the syntax like this==> **conn.Open "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=E:\VBA_Project_Demo\Demo\demo.db;"** but getting same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing a SQLite Database in VBA in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509154/accessing-a-sqlite-database-in-vba-in-excel)

Comment: have a look at [Using an Access, MySQL, PostgreSQL or SQLite database from VBA](http://pragmateek.com/using-an-access-mysql-postgresql-or-sqlite-database-from-vba/)

Comment: @OurManinBananas thanks for the response, i have used that syntax only, even am getting the same error, what i have mentioned :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to connect SQLite, you download ODBC Driver at (or another source)
http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/

Then modify the connection.

Hope it helps.

```
Sub LoadValues()

   Dim conn As Object, rst As Object

   Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

  ' OPEN CONNECTION
   conn.Open "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=c:\mydb.db;LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;"   'Am getting Error at this line

  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM test "

  ' OPEN RECORDSET
   rst.Open strSQL, conn

   ' OUTPUT TO WORKSHEET
   Worksheets("results").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst
   rst.Close

  ' FREE RESOURCES
 Set rst = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: ,thanks for the response,but i tried with the syntax, that you have mentioned but am getting same error

Comment: Did you install 32/64 bit? Can you go to control panel to add ODBC link?

Comment: i have installed 64 bit,and  have added the ODBC link also in control panel

Comment: Then you can do "conn.Open DSN"

Comment: Can you retry the system DNS?

Comment: please check your path to the db: `c:\mydb.db`

Comment: Hi Guys, Actually i executed the syntax mentioned above in the different machine, with the same database (SQLite) and the respective driver, it is working fine, i am still not getting what was the issue in that machine that it is not working with the same syntax and same machine configurations

Answer (score 0):

use 32bit odbc driver. 64bit not comaptible

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.