# Loop FASTER through folders, subfolders and collect file names+path VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i tryed few codes, but they works too slow. We have like half million files in server which i need to loop. And result is like only 3-4 k in 5 mins :) Maybe you guys idea how to do this code loop faster? thank you in advance

```
Option Explicit
Sub getfiles()

    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object, sf
    Dim i As Integer, colFolders As New Collection, ws As Worksheet, y As Integer
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder('my path)
    
    colFolders.Add oFolder
    
    DoEvents
    Do While colFolders.Count > 0
        Set oFolder = colFolders(1)
        colFolders.Remove 1
    
        For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
            If Right(oFile.Name, 4) = ".pdf" Then
                ws.Cells(i + 1, 1) = oFolder.Path
                ws.Cells(i + 1, 2) = oFile.Name
                i = i + 1
                y = y + 1
                If y = 2000 Then 'just saving to check result after few minutes with pause
                    ThisWorkbook.Save
                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
                    y = 0
                End If
            End If
        Next oFile
        For Each sf In oFolder.SubFolders
            colFolders.Add sf
        Next sf
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: What percentage of these files are PDFs?

Comment: Change the `FileSystemObject` with `Dir`, it's much faster.

Answer (score 3):

This should be faster:

```
Option Explicit

Sub getPdfFiles()
    Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim output As Object
    Set output = ShellOutput("Dir D:\BYoung\*.pdf /s /b /a:-d")
    
    Dim inLines() As String
    Dim sLine As String, lines As Long
    
    Do While Not output.AtEndOfStream
        sLine = output.ReadLine
    
        If Right(sLine, 4) = ".pdf" Then
            i = i + 1
            ReDim Preserve inLines(1 To i)
            inLines(i) = sLine
        End If
        'If i Mod 100 = 0 Then DoEvents
    Loop
    lines = i
    
    Dim fName As String, fFull As String, fPath As String
    Dim outLines As Variant
    ReDim outLines(1 To lines, 1 To 2)
    
    For i = 1 To lines
        fFull = inLines(i)
        fName = Right(fFull, Len(fFull) - InStrRev(fFull, "\"))
        fPath = Mid(fFull, 1, Len(fFull) - Len(fName))
        outLines(i, 1) = fPath
        outLines(i, 2) = fName
        'If i Mod 100 = 0 Then DoEvents
    Next i
    
    ws.Range("A1:B" & lines) = outLines
    
    ws.Parent.Save
End Sub
```

Which calls this function:

```
' Create a Shell, executes a command, and returns the output stream
'(from @BrianBurns at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32600510/109122)
Public Function ShellOutput(sCmd As String) As Object
    Dim oShell As Object
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    'run command
    Dim oExec As Object
    Dim oOutput As Object
    Set oExec = oShell.Exec("cmd.exe /c " & sCmd)
    Set oOutput = oExec.StdOut

    Set ShellOutput = oOutput
End Function
```

Comment: Great. For 350k files, it took 10s on my machine. There are a few issues though. `i` needs to be declared as long. `y` needs to be removed. To exclude a directory named `MyFiles.PDF` you could add the switch `a:-d`. `ReDim inLines(1 To 1)` is redundant since you have used the 'array parentheses' when declaring. You forgot to remove the line `ReDim Preserve inLines(1 To i + 1)`. Since you have used the `ActiveSheet` for the worksheet, for the workbook it would be more correct to use `ws.Parent` instead of `ThisWorkbook`. Could you share what exactly the purpose of `DoEvents` is in this code?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Good points, I was in a rush when I posted this (leaving for a trip) and didn't clean-up completely, I will make some changes.  RE: DoEvents, I started by taking the OPs code, testing it in my environment and then transforming the necessary parts.  When I do that, I usually put in `DoEvents` so that I can break out of any infinite or long-running loops, even in my own code (in case of mistake), without having to restart and recover my Spreadsheet.  It's probably unnecessary now.

Comment: (I was talking about the 2nd `DoEvents`, which I added, the first one was leftover from the original code).

Comment: @VBasic2008  Ok, I've cleaned it up, there was other stuff too, most importantly that I forgot the attribution to BrianBurns for the Shell-wrapper function.  This was sloppy of me, and I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `Dir()` for files:

```vb
Sub Tester()
   Dim matches As Collection
   
   Set matches = GetMatches("C:\Test", "*.pdf")

   'loop matches and list file info...
    
End Sub


'Return a collection of file objects given a starting folder and a file pattern
'  e.g. "*.txt"
'Pass False for last parameter if don't want to check subfolders
Function GetMatches(startFolder As String, filePattern As String, _
                    Optional subFolders As Boolean = True) As Collection

    Dim fso, fldr, f, subFldr, fpath
    Dim colFiles As New Collection
    Dim colSub As New Collection
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    colSub.Add startFolder
    
    Do While colSub.Count > 0
        
        Set fldr = fso.getfolder(colSub(1))
        colSub.Remove 1
        
        If subFolders Then
            For Each subFldr In fldr.subFolders
                colSub.Add subFldr.Path
            Next subFldr
        End If
        
        fpath = fldr.Path
        If Right(fpath, 1) <> "\" Then fpath = fpath & "\"
        f = Dir(fpath & filePattern)'Dir is faster...
        Do While Len(f) > 0
            colFiles.Add fso.getfile(fpath & f)
            f = Dir()
        Loop
    Loop
    Set GetMatches = colFiles
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

### Write a List of Files to a Worksheet

- Copy the code to a standard module, e.g. `Module1`, in the workbook with the worksheet you plan to write to.
- Then, before running the one-liner `WritePdfFoldersAndFiles` procedure, carefully adjust the arguments of the called procedure (`WriteFoldersAndFiles`) in it.
- To learn about the `Dir` parameters (switches) visit the Microsoft Docs' [`dir`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir) page.

```vb
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      From a folder ('"C:\"') and all its subfolders ('/s'), returns
'               all PDF ("*.pdf") file names (second column) and their
'               folder paths (first column) in two columns of worksheet 'Sheet1'
'               in the workbook containing this code, starting with cell 'A2'.
'               The '/b' switch is necessary to get the file paths.
'               The 'a-d' switch is necessary to exclude directories.
' Remarks:      If you select all files (*.*) on your system drive (e.g. 'C:\'),
'               there may be a different number of files on each run due to
'               newly created logs, temp files, or whatnot.
' Calls:        'WriteFoldersAndFiles'
'                   'ArrFilePaths'
'                   'GetFoldersAndFiles'
'                       'SplitStringByLastCharToRow'
'                   'WriteDataSimple'
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub WritePdfFoldersAndFiles()
     
    ' Adjust (play with) the values in this line:
    WriteFoldersAndFiles "C:\", "*.pdf", "/s/b/a-d", "Sheet1", "A2"

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes a list of folder paths and file names to two columns
'               of a worksheet in the workbook containing this code.
' Calls:        'ArrFilePaths'
'               'GetFoldersAndFiles'
'                   'SplitStringByLastCharToRow'
'               'WriteDataSimple'
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub WriteFoldersAndFiles( _
        ByVal FolderPath As String, _
        Optional ByVal DirPattern As String = "*.*", _
        Optional ByVal DirSwitches As String = "/s/b/a-d", _
        Optional ByVal WorksheetName As String = "Sheet1", _
        Optional ByVal FirstCellAddress As String = "A1")
    Const ProcName As String = "WriteFoldersAndFiles"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const tf As String = "0.0000"
    Dim t As Double, tt As Double, tc As Double, ti As Double
    ti = Timer: t = ti

    ' Write the file paths to an array ('fPaths').
    Dim fPaths() As String
    fPaths = ArrFilePaths(FolderPath, DirPattern, DirSwitches)
    
    tc = Timer: Debug.Print "ArrFilePaths...          " _
        & Format(tc - t, tf) & "(" & Format(tc - ti, tf) & ")": t = tc

    ' Split the file paths by the last path separator, to folder paths
    ' and file names, into a 2D one-based two-column array ('Data').
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = GetFoldersAndFiles(fPaths)
    'Erase fPaths ' probably nothing to gain
    
    tc = Timer: Debug.Print "GetFoldersAndFiles...    " _
        & Format(tc - t, tf) & "(" & Format(tc - ti, tf) & ")": t = tc

    ' Write the values from the 2D array to a worksheet in the workbook
    ' containing this code ('ThisWorkbook').
    WriteDataSimple ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WorksheetName) _
        .Range(FirstCellAddress), Data
    
    tc = Timer: Debug.Print "WriteDataSimple...       " _
        & Format(tc - t, tf) & "(" & Format(tc - ti, tf) & ")": t = tc

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the file paths of the files in a folder in an array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function ArrFilePaths( _
    ByVal FolderPath As String, _
    Optional ByVal FilePattern As String = "*.*", _
    Optional ByVal DirSwitches As String = "/s/b/a-d") _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "ArrFilePaths"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then FolderPath = FolderPath & pSep
    Dim ExecString As String ' '%comspec%' or 'cmd.exe' ?
    ExecString = "%comspec% /c Dir """ _
        & FolderPath & FilePattern & """ " & DirSwitches
    ArrFilePaths = Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell") _
        .Exec(ExecString).StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf)

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      From an array containing file paths, returns
'               the folder paths and the file names in two columns
'               of a 2D one-based two-column array.
' Calls:        'SplitStringByLastCharToRow'.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetFoldersAndFiles( _
    ByVal FilePaths As Variant) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "GetFoldersAndFiles"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    Dim nLB As Long: nLB = LBound(FilePaths)
    Dim nUB As Long: nUB = UBound(FilePaths)
    
    Dim Data() As String: ReDim Data(1 To nUB - nLB, 1 To 2)
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = nLB To nUB - 1 ' last item is an empty string
        r = r + 1
        SplitStringByLastCharToRow Data, r, FilePaths(n), pSep
    Next n
    
    GetFoldersAndFiles = Data

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes the values from a 2D one-based array ('Data') to a range
'               defined by its first cell ('FirstCell') and by the size
'               of the array. Optionally (by default), previously
'               clears the columns (preserving the data above (e.g. headers)).
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub WriteDataSimple( _
        ByVal FirstCell As Range, _
        ByVal Data As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal DoClearContents As Boolean = True)
    Const ProcName As String = "WriteDataSimple"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    With FirstCell.Resize(, UBound(Data, 2))
        If DoClearContents Then
            .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).Clear
        End If
        .Resize(UBound(Data, 1)).Value = Data
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Splits a string ('SplitString') by the last occurrence
'               of a character ('SplitChar') and writes the two split strings
'               to the first two columns in a row ('DataRow')
'               of a 2D one-based array ('Data').
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub SplitStringByLastCharToRow( _
        ByRef Data As Variant, _
        ByVal DataRow As Long, _
        ByVal SplitString As String, _
        ByVal SplitChar As String)
    Const ProcName As String = "SplitStringByLastCharToRow"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim lcPos As Long: lcPos = InStrRev(SplitString, SplitChar)
    If lcPos = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Data(DataRow, 1) = Mid(SplitString, 1, lcPos - 1)
    Data(DataRow, 2) = Mid(SplitString, lcPos + 1, Len(SplitString) - lcPos)
'    Data(DataRow, 1) = Left(SplitString, lcPos - 1)
'    Data(DataRow, 2) = Right(SplitString, Len(SplitString) - lcPos)

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```